# Why do I get "Resource id #4" when I apply print_r() to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i “echo” a “Resource id #6” from a MySql response in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

Below is the code:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from choices where a_id='$taskid'")or die(mysql_error());
print_r($result);
```

I get "Resource id #4", any idea?

After I added

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ print_r($row); }
```

I just got `[]`

What's wrong?

Comment: print_r will only accept arrays and objects. If you use var_dump() it will give you information on whatever you give it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to print a mysql [resource variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) instead of the values contained within the resource it references. You must first try to extract the values you have gotten by using a function such as  [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

You might also try [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php), but I find associative arrays quite nice as they allow you to access their values by the field name as in [Mike's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777801/why-do-i-get-resource-id-4-when-i-apply-printr-to-an-array-in-php/1777805#1777805).

Answer (score 17):

`mysql_query()` does not return an array as [explained in the manual](http://php.net/mysql_query). Use `mysql_fetch_array()`, `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, or `mysql_fetch_row()` with your `$result`. See the link above for more info on how to manipulate query results.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`$result` is a resource variable returned by `mysql_query`. More about resource variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

You must use other functions such as `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get the array of the query resultset.

```
$resultset = array();
$result=mysql_query("select * from choices where a_id='$taskid'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $resultset[] = $row; // fetch each row...
}
mysql_free_result($result); // optional though...

print_r($resultset);
```

#### See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

[Resources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) are special variable types used by PHP to track external resources like database connections, file handles, sockets, etc.