# Why did I only got [] from print_r($row); in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Below is the code:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from choices where a_id='$taskid'")or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ print_r($row); }
```

Why did I only got `[]`? What's wrong?

More:
It can not be empty. The more complete code is as follows:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from choices where a_id='$taskid'")or die(mysql_error());
   $resultset=array();
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{  
    $temp=shuffle(array_slice($row,3));

    $row1=array_splice($row,3,7,$temp);
    $resultset[]=$row1;

}

echo json_encode($resultset);
```

I want to shuffle the mysql query results from index 3 to index 7, only to find that the values from index 3 to index 7 are returned  without being shuffled. Other values are `undefined` in Javascript.

What's wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate from your own question asked 30min. ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777801/why-do-i-get-resource-id-4-when-i-apply-printr-to-an-array-in-php .

Comment: I think you should post what is inside the database and what the value of $taskid at the time of execution.

Answer (score 1):

$row is empty.  Meaning nothing was returned from your SQL query.  Try the following to make sure the query is executing exactly what you expect:

```
echo "select * from choices where a_id='$taskid'";
```

Comment: Are you sure?  It seems like if that were the case the code should never go into the while loop in the first place.