# How do i "echo" a "Resource id #6" from a MySql response in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

very simple question, i have this:

```
$datos1=mysql_query("SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), '" . $row['fecha'] . "');");
echo($datos1);
```

But the result is: **Resource id #6**

How can i print the result in the way is meant to be? Thanks!

Comment: There is [quite a number of duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[php]%20[mysql]%20%22resource%20id%22%20result) asking essentially the same question. I've voted to close a few of them as duplicates of this one here, as this is among the oldes ones, and phrased in a sufficiently clear and concise fashion to serve as the canonical version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a fetch function. for example:

```
$result = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), '%s') as time_delta", $row['fecha']));
if($result){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $data['time_delta'];
}
```

However, i wouldnt use the `mysql` functions unless absolutely necessary. the `mysql` extension [is NOT recommended for use in new projects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php). Instead you should use [`PDO` with `PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: +1 PDO, not mysqli.  Only use mysqli if you are really, really sure that you're going to want to torture yourself with mysql forever and never switch to something else.