# Why does this return Resource id #2?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i “echo” a “Resource id #6” from a MySql response in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

I am new at php and SQL and I'm trying to make the php page list the numbers of enries in the table.
I'm using this code but it returns Resource id #2:

```
$rt=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons");
echo mysql_error();
echo "<h1>Number:</h1>".$rt;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you get a mysql ressource when you do a [`mysql_query()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Use something like [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://ch2.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to get the next row. It returns an array with the column names as indices. In your case it's probably `COUNT(*)`.

Here's a fix and some minor improvements of your snippet:

```
$rt = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rt);
if($row)
    echo "<h1>Number:</h1>" . $row[0];
```

If you need to get all rows of the resultset use this snippet:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rt)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$rt=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons");
echo mysql_error();
$count = mysql_result($rt, 0, 0);
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, [resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) are returned from certain functions so that they can be passed to other related functions. Examples include database connections, database query results, file-handles, etc.

According to the documentation on [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), a SELECT query returns a resource. You can take that resource and pass it to a number of different functions. To retrieve a count of the rows, you can use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), to retrieve the results of the query, you can use either [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php).

A normal pattern for dealing with database results will look something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons"); // run query against database
$count = mysql_num_rows($result); // retrieve a count of the rows in the previous query
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // loop through all the rows in the resultset
    // use $row['column_name'] to access columns in your resultset
}
```

From your example above:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM persons"); // run query against db
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // retrieve the 1 (and only) row
$count = $row['num']; // we needed to alias the COUNT(*) column as `num`
```

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_query()` doesn't return a value, it returns a resource (see [here](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in the manual).

The returned result resource should be passed to another function for dealing with result tables (like [mysql_fetch_array()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)), to access the returned data.

Example based on your initial code:

```
$rt=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM persons");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rt)) {
  var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns a resource object. You need to fetch rows from it first (`mysql_fetch_row`).

Answer (score 1):

Straight from PHP.net.......

"For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error."

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN
>   and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a
>   resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.