# How to echo a query

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this return Resource id #2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794927/why-does-this-return-resource-id-2)

I want to echo `mysql_query("SELECT SUM(onlineplayers) FROM servers")` but when I place echo in front, it says Resource Id #2 and when I add `or die(mysql_error());` at the end, it just outputs 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794927/why-does-this-return-resource-id-2

Comment: WHAT? what do you mean with *when I place echo in front*?

Comment: The return type of `mysql_query()` is not a string result of your query, it is a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) (in your case at least). [Read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: the mysql_query() executes the query and returns the output, hence you are getting the output has Resource #2. to output the query you need to assign the query to a variable and echo the variable and pass it to the mysql_query function

Comment: 1) Yogesh Suthar is correct.  To echo your query string, put it in a variable and echo the variable.  2) You should really be using mysqli or PDO instead of the (old, deprecated) "mysql_query()" API.  3) You should also use prepared statements whenever possible.  *MOST IMPORTANT* - 4) you can't just "echo the results of a query".  You need to call an API to *fetch* the results.  Then you can display what you fetch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the query first:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(onlineplayers) FROM servers");
if($result){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $data[0];
}
```

However, you shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions unless absolutely necessary. the `mysql` extension [is NOT recommended](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) for use in new projects. Instead you should use PDO_mysql or mysqli

**Source:** [Why does this return Resource id #2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794927/why-does-this-return-resource-id-2)

Answer (score 1):

use this below code

```
$str = "SELECT SUM(onlineplayers) FROM servers";  //this will set the query in string format
echo $str;    // this will echo the query;
mysql_query($str);   // this will run the query
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain it too well. I want to echo the output of `mysql_query("SELECT SUM(onlineplayers) FROM servers");`

Comment: @Enigmo if you want to see the output of the query then it will show you `Resource Id #2` this.

Comment: @Enigmo and if you want to see the result of the query use this functions `mysql_fetch_*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(onlineplayers) as `total` FROM servers"); // notice the "as `total`
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q); // will return the result
echo $r['total']; // will echo the count
```

On a sidenote, please stop using `mysql_*` functions. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "SELECT SUM(onlineplayers) FROM servers"; 
echo $str; 
$result = mysql_query($str); 
$row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row);
```