# PHP var_dump returns reesource(16)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, output

I have the following code:

```
function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
    $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

    $sql = "SELECT
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
                            `conversations_messages`.`message_text`,
                            `users`.`user_name`
                    FROM `conversations_messages`
                    INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
                    INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
                    WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
                    AND `conversations_members`.`user_id` = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
                    ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    var_dump($result);
    $messages = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
            $messages[] = array(
                    'date'          => $row['message_date'],
                    'unread'        => $row['message_unread'],
                    'text'          => $row['message_text'],
                    'user_name'     => $row['user_name'],
            );
    }
    var_dump( $messages );
```

}

It should return something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 1322254667 [text] => one [user_name] => bob ) )
```

However, it returns

```
resource(16) of type (mysql result) array(0) { }
```

I am completely new to PHP and MySQL, but I have tried checking for typos, echoing mysql_error, and killing the script at an error, which shows that there is no error in the SQL.

I do not know what has gone wrong and how to fix it.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like your query failed ?

Comment: I thought that but I cannot see how; do you have any ideas?

Comment: try with `echo count($messages);` if print 0 no result is find in your query

Comment: I did that, but all I got was resource(16) of type (mysql result) 0

Answer (score 1):

`var_dump($result);` shows `resource(16) of type (mysql result)` means your query is ok.

`var_dump($messages);` shows empty array means the result of your query is empty.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for how to fix it.  Would sending you the SQL file be a goood idea, as I am a complete noob in MySQL and PHP

Comment: @user3308065 print your sql and try run it in mysql client, fix the sql is your job :).

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT `conversations_messages`.`message_date`' at line 1 comes out of PhpMyAdmin

Comment: then you have a problem in the query

Comment: OK, but (n00b question alert) how do I fix it?

Comment: It turns out I'd put speechmarks at the beginning and end of the query, there are still errors though

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` function is expected to return [`resource`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) when your query is valid.

For you to see the actual returned result of your query, use row fetching functions like `mysql_fetch_assoc`, `mysql_fetch_object`, and the like. In your case, you put the fetched values in your **$row** variable, so you may use var_dump on it.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        var_dump($row);
}
```

Try to check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794927/why-does-this-return-resource-id-2).

Answer (score 0):

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, `mysql_query()` returns a [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) on success, or FALSE on error.

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, `mysql_query()` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.