# Count all values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering how I can make this work,
I tried:

```
$query = "SELECT author, SUM(likes) FROM posts WHERE author = '$usern' GROUP BY likes order by SUM(likes) + 0 desc"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

But it just gives me number of likes of first post, not from all posts in-one.
So, I need to get all likes from all posts where username is $usern

Database rows: id, likes, author, date

I need to output one number, e.g. 50 if the author has 5 posts and on every post 10 likes

Comment: If you get rid of the GROUP BY, you get what you want. You only need GROUP BY if you want a query that performs the calculation for all authors.

Comment: Hello, thanks for comment, I dont need from all authors, I need just from author named '$usern', I need from all posts where is author named like that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only want the total number of likes for `$usern`, this simple query will already suffice:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(likes) FROM posts WHERE author = '$usern'";
```

You only need a GROUP BY only if you want to retrieve this information for multiple authors at once:

```
$query = "SELECT author, SUM(likes) FROM posts GROUP BY author ORDER BY SUM(likes) + 0 DESC";
```

Comment: I can't see your printscreen - can you post the output as code? That will be more useful...

Comment: Okay, I got "Resource id #19" But I should got "19"

Comment: Then there's something wrong with how you output your code. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794927/why-does-this-return-resource-id-2) might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `author`, SUM(`likes`) FROM `posts` WHERE `author` = $user;
```

this query will show you how many likes have got `$user` under all his posts