# what is the notice: resource id#9?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i “echo” a “Resource id #6” from a MySql response in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

I created a SELECT query but it has an error. When I print_r(result) I get the resource id#9 
notice here is the code:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM {$hotel_name} WHERE Bdate BETWEEN {$chack_in} AND {$chack_out}";

$availability = mysql_query($query);

confirm_query($availability);

print_r($availability);
```

Comment: user605505, it took me about three months to learn that #9 was not code for which error occurred. It's a lack of a usable result from your query. And surprisingly so few places tell you this! Just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: what is `confirm_query`?  I am not familiar with it, and didnt find anything when i searched PHP manual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'$availability` prints as 'resource id#9' because it is a resource.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

There is nothing wrong with this, it is expected.  `mysql_query` returns resource types when the query executes successful, and `false` when it fails.  You can call `mysql_fetch_*($resource)` on that resource to get data from it.

(Where * is `assoc`, `object`, `array`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

$availability is the handle to the results, the fact it says #9 would imply it worked. You then need to loop through getting the results from $availability.

Comment: $availability_per_date= mysql_fetch_assoc($availability)
print_r($availability_per_date); //gives me nothing i'm using before it mysql_num_fields which gives me the num of fields could it be the intenal pointer that i should reset?

Comment: As above, using mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc etc, will return the rows. If you take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php it has a good number of examples. The PHP manual is incredibly good at examples