# Error in query, what is Resource id #9?

Tags: php

I have following code..

```
$query = "SELECT quote, author FROM quotes ORDER BY id DESC";
$resut = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

echo $result; //for debuggin purpose

while($result_set =  mysql_fetch_array($result)) {      
    echo '<div class="pullquote">';
    echo $result_set['quote'];
    echo ' - ';
    echo $result_set['author'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

and this doesn't works! The table is not empty FYI, all I see in the output is:

> Resource id #9

I am not being able to figure out what this `Resource id #9` means.
As I tested `SELECT quote, author FROM quotes ORDER BY id DESC` in phpmyadmin, that just works fine and produces desired result, but not in here. I wonder what is wrong with the code or something?

If I do following,

```
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
var_dump ($array);
```

It returns, `bool(false)`. What does that mean here?

Comment: Where is `$connection` defined? Also, note the spelling difference between `$result` and `$resut`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523840/what-is-the-notice-resource-id9 might help.

Comment: solved.. typo, there is RESUT instead or resu[L]t.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is a "Resource"?

There's nothing *wrong* with `Resource id #9` (this just means you have a resource). Note [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) on this topic:

> For `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE`, `EXPLAIN` and other statements returning `resultset`, `mysql_query()` returns a `resource` on success, or `FALSE` on error.

So if you have "Resource," it means your query didn't fail.

#### Watch for Typos

Additionally, you are setting `$resut`, and attempting to access `$result`. Note the missing "l".