# Resource ID# being shown - PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am running the following script to draw a table from results in my database:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

$currentUser = $user->id;

$query = "SELECT * FROM jos_modelform_submissions WHERE user_id='".$currentUser."' AND model_type='model1'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$tableResults = $db->query();

$formLayout .= $tableResults;

echo "<div style='overflow:auto;'><table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='14'>
<tr bgcolor='#0D7CCD'>";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;' width='25px'><b>ID</b></TD>
<TD style='text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;' width='40px'><b>User ID</b></TD>
<TD style='text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;' width='200px'><b>Input</b></TD>
<TD style='text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;' width='600px'><b>Output</b></TD>
<TD style='text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;' width='110px'><b>Model Type</b></TD>
<TD style='text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;' width='100px'><b>Date/Time</b></TD>
</tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan ='6'><div style='width:1075px;height:300px;overflow:auto;'><table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='14'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tableResults)) 
{
$mix = array("<", "/>", ">", "/");
$output1 = str_replace($mix, "#", $row['output']);
$output2 = str_replace("#", "<BR/>", $output1);
echo "<tr onclick=\"alert('Test');\" onmouseover=\"document.body.style.cursor='pointer'\" onmouseout=\"document.body.style.cursor='default'\">";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='25px'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='40px'>" . $row['user_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD width='200px'>" . $row['input'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD width='600px'>" .stripslashes($output2). "</td>";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='110px'>" . $row['model_type'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='100px'>" . $row['date_time'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table> </div></td></tr></table></div></br></br>";
```

The table presents fine but at the bottom of my page I am getting the output of the Resource ID#. How can I get rid of this? Is there an error in my syntax or logic somewhere? You can see the code running here:

http://hanseninfotech.com/rtds/index.php/modelform1

Comment: Simplify your question and include only relevant code.

Comment: This is all relevant. It's all the same script. The call to the database is made in the first part but the error is presented after the form is displayed.

Comment: Where do you handle the error? I mean : "or die(mysql_error());"

Comment: I don't. I didn't think i had to. I am using Joomla!'s built in class to access the same database i am already in.

Comment: @hanleyhansen: No, it's not all relevant. It _can't be_. Narrow it down to 5-10 lines at most. Abstract away. It's called _debugging_.

Comment: @hanleyhansen: Read the comments. This is localised, and also doesn't appear to have been debugged. There is no testcase. It's never going to help anyone else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i "echo" a "Resource id #6" from a MySql response in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you echo `$formLayout ?`

From your code :

```
$tableResults = $db->query();
$formLayout .= $tableResults;   // what does this line do ????
```

echoing the return from a query() will result in the output of "Resource ###"

echoing a file handle (returned from fopen()) will produce the same result

Comment: At no point do I echo $formLayout. But they might within their code. This is within an extension called RSForms. I have to concatenate to $formLayout because that is the variable that holds the form layout (lol). That is what that line does.

Comment: @hanleyhansen $tableResults at that point is "Resource #<a number>" - im betting thats causing the problem - try commenting that line out and see what happens ...

Comment: That worked! But i don't understand why. Guess I was misinformed.

Comment: @hanleyhansen I dont know Joomla .... but $tableResults is not something that should be displayed from end ...

Comment: See, this is exactly the sort of thing that you should have ruled out in debugging. This logic was _not_ in the question.

Comment: @hanleyhansen I would suggest this probably happened because you cut and pasted code without fully understanding what you were doing ...

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you dont't handle if you have a zero element.

```
if (!$tableResults = $db->query()) {
    echo $db->stderr();
    return false;
  }
```

Also you used Joomla's function previously , why don't you use it again? Instead of using mysql functions , use $row = $db->loadAssocList(); and foreach.

```
$row = $db->loadAssocList();
foreach ($row as $key=>$value) 
{
$mix = array("<", "/>", ">", "/");
$output1 = str_replace($mix, "#", $value['output']);
$output2 = str_replace("#", "<BR/>", $output1);
echo "<tr onclick=\"alert('Test');\" onmouseover=\"document.body.style.cursor='pointer'\" onmouseout=\"document.body.style.cursor='default'\">";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='25px'>" . $value['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='40px'>" .$value['user_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD width='200px'>" . $value['input'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD width='600px'>" .stripslashes($output2). "</td>";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='110px'>" . $value['model_type'] . "</td>";
echo "<TD style='text-align:center;' width='100px'>" . $value['date_time'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

MAybe it helps.

Also my opinion about the HTML part : Putting HTML into a PHP code is khm... So old-fashioned  programming style, I think. Try to avoid to mix PHP and HTML like the example above . Try to use HTML in a  HTML files , php codes in a php files , and  just minimally mix them. I recommend to use any  CMS  or template engine , and separate the php and the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not output a resource ID.