# SQL Resource ID #4 from SELECT COUNT?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i “echo” a “Resource id #6” from a MySql response in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

I have a statement:

```
      $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(author) FROM userpages WHERE `author` = '" . $userid . "'") or die();
      echo $query1;
```

Ignore the amazingly awful naming convention their, its just for testing it before i beef it up. Because im not actually getting data from the table i should just be able to echo the statement shouldnt i? However its giving me an error.

The error is: Resource id #4

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the error you're receiving?

Comment: @DanNewhouse I added or die() onto it, no change the error is just: Resource id #4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Returned values:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

And:

> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.

Comment: So, would that mean i have to put like while mysql_fetch_array and have $row = data kinda thing? I tried that but i dont know what the data would be due to the fact im not retrieving any :/

Comment: But you are retrieving data, you're retrieving a count of the number of userpages for a specific author.... that's data as well

Comment: You can do something like this: `$result = array(); while( false!==($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) )$result[] = $row;` to fetch the data and, then, `var_dump($result);` to see what data is fetched. Also, in your example, in query `SELECT COUNT(..) FROM...`, the only one row can be fetched. So, you can simply do `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);` and, then, `var_dump($row);`

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query returns a resultset resource, you have to loop through the resultset using

```
mysql_fetch_array($query1)
```

(or similar) to retrieve each record. It doesn't matter whether the query returns 1 row or 100,000 rows, the principle is the same

please read the [relevant sections of the manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) that explain this in great detail before feeling the need to ask for help.... reading the manual is your friend!

**EDIT**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
   echo $row['COUNT(author)'];   
}
```

or change your SQL query to

```
  $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(author) AS authorcount FROM userpages WHERE `author` = '" . $userid . "'") or die();
```

and then

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

will return an array with an index of 'authorcount'

```
echo $row['authorcount'];
```

Comment: And then perhaps consider using mysqli or pdo instead of the horrendously outdated mysql

Comment: Ahh thank you! The php manual is really hard for me to understand i dont know why i never have been able to digest any of it :( thanks though i will have a look through

Comment: Just look at example #2 on the page I've linked

Comment: Okay thanks, but isnt that returning data from different columns in the database? I just want a count, when i did it in my computing classes in comp sci just doing SELECT COUNT worked fine :/ i must be missing something huge :/ sorry for been dumb here ^^

Comment: The result of a COUNT is still data, you're using a SELECT statement to retrieve it in exactly the same way you'd use SELECT userId FROM users to retrieve data

Comment: So where i have      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) 
    { 
      $numOfPosts = $row['author'];
    }   
what would i have instead of ['author'] ? is this right?

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will be helpfull

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(author) as cnt FROM userpages WHERE `author` = '" . $userid . "'";
echo $query;
$res = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   print_r($row);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! getting closer, i get this now: Array ( [0] => 5 [COUNT(author)] => 5 )

Comment: @KubaW Please, avoid direct variable assignment in if/while/etc.. It is better to use `while ( false!==($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) )`

Comment: I've changed my snippet a little, try now. please red this: [function.mysql-fetch-array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)