# Resource id #.. sql on php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with sql on php and I get `Resource id #...`,

For e.g. `Resource id #21`,

What does it mean? and where can I find a table with all the meaning of these ids?

Thanks

Comment: Could you expand your question? We need more info.

Comment: Can you show the code? It looks like you are printing the resource returned by mysql_query, instead of passing it to  mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc.

Comment: Resource #... have you used mysql_fetch_array to read the returned Resource?

Comment: It seems like you have tried echo'ing the result of a `mysql_query` or `mysqli_query` instead of using `mysql_fetch_array` or similar.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Before you begin, you may read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer/.
Now, post your code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i "echo" a "Resource id #6" from a MySql response in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch your actual result from received via `mysql_query()` command result.
For example after code

```
 $res = mysql_query("some query");
```

This returned result resource should be passed to `mysql_fetch_array()`, and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the returned data.

Example:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

If you need more then one row from your result you have to use loops.

The documentation regarding usage of these functions you can find here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

Comment: worth mentioning that (a) the OP didn't specify which DB he's using, and (b) even if he is using MySQL, he shouldn't be using the `mysql_xx` functions. Use PDO or `mysqli_xx` functions instead.