# resource id # 53 error in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i “echo” a “Resource id #6” from a MySql response in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

Hey guys, I got an error when I try to run my code in PHP.
It displays resource id #53 in my screen. All I want is to count only the total of one of my field but I'm stuck with this error. Here's my code below:

```
$last_points = mysql_insert_id();
//echo $last_points , display like 12... no error
$fkid = $last_points;   // no error....
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downline WHERE fkmember = {$fkid}";
$execute = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
echo $execute; //display error why?
```

Help me guys please. I think it's my query.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `resource id #53` is not an error. You are displaying a `resource`, not the output of the query.

To show the output, use:

```
$last_points = mysql_insert_id();
//echo $last_points , display like 12... no error
$fkid = $last_points;   // no error....
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downline WHERE fkmember = {$fkid}";
$execute = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($execute)); //display error why?
```

Secondly, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should look into learning and utilising the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) libraries accordingly.

Comment: i got Array ( [0] => 0 [COUNT(*)] => 0 ) means no data right?

Comment: It means there were no results `WHERE fkmember = {$fkid}`

Comment: i looked up it in my table there are 23 records. how can i get the records total?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to `echo` a resultset(as received because of `mysql_query`) do this:

```
print_r( mysql_fetch_array($execute) );
```

Answer (score 0):

By codeigniter way

**In Model:**

```
function getCount($fkid)
        {
            $Qry = "SELECT * FROM downline WHERE fkmember = $fkid};
            $query = $this->db->query($Qry);
            return $query->num_rows();
        }
```

**In controller:**

```
echo $Count = $this->modelname->getCount($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

$execute is an array so you need to print it among echoing it

```
print_r($execute);
```