# Getting a Value for a Cell in Squl

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “Resource id #4” when I apply print_r() to an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777801/why-do-i-get-resource-id-4-when-i-apply-print-r-to-an-array-in-php)

Pardon this simple question, however I am a rookie to SQL and PHP.  Simply enough I am trying to get the value of a cell that I know the column it is in as well as the row it's in so I can use that value in a simple subtraction problem. Here is what I have:

```
$outtime = mysql_query("SELECT `Event1CheckOut1`
    FROM attendance
    WHERE ID = '1234'");

$intime = mysql_query("SELECT `Event1CheckIn1`
    FROM attendance
    WHERE ID = '1234'");

$dur = $outtime - $intime;
```

Using echo it returned the result for the first one as "Resource id #4".  Doing some research I think this may be because it is returning to me a table of the results not simply a value.  It may be worth noting that the values I am trying to fetch are times in a 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks instead of single quotes to escape column/table names:

```
SELECT `Event1CheckIn1` FROM `attendance` WHERE ID='1234'
```

Also, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I changed all of them and it didn't fix the problem, I appreciate the advice though because I had assumed backticks to be the same as apostropies

Comment: I've done some more research and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777801/why-do-i-get-resource-id-4-when-i-apply-print-r-to-an-array-in-php).  Note that these functions are obsolete (my edit above).

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the result set

```
$outtimeR = mysql_query("SELECT `Event1CheckOut1`
    FROM attendance
    WHERE ID = '1234'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($outtimeR )){
  $outtime = $row['Event1CheckOut1']; 
}

$intimeR = mysql_query("SELECT `Event1CheckIn1`
    FROM attendance
    WHERE ID = '1234'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($intimeR )){
  $intime = $row['Event1CheckIn1']; 
}

$dur = $outtime - $intime;
```