# why do i get the result in $result

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “Resource id #4” when I apply print_r() to an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777801/why-do-i-get-resource-id-4-when-i-apply-print-r-to-an-array-in-php)
>   [How do i “echo” a “Resource id #6” from a MySql response in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290108/how-do-i-echo-a-resource-id-6-from-a-mysql-response-in-php)

why do i get "Resource id #6" as result in $result? want 1 or 0 :P

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE rchat=1 LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
unlink($fn);
//$fn = $_SESSION['sess_user'].'.txt';
$fn = 'hittaingen.txt';
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET rchat=1 room='" . $_SESSION['sess_user'] . "' WHERE     user='" . $_SESSION['sess_user'] . "'");
}

else {
  //$fn = $result['room'].'.txt';
  $fn = 'hitta.txt';
  mysql_query("UPDATE members SET rchat=2 room='" . $result['room'] . "' WHERE user='" . $_SESSION['sess_user'] . "'");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_query()` returns just a reference of the result object and not the result itself. So in order to get you 0 or 1, you got to parse the result first using, e.g., [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
```

Besides, you should definitely look into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), as the the `mysql_X()` functions are marked as deprecated and generally not considered safe against SQL injections!