# Array can not be displayed

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code

```
$hasil = "INSERT INTO pendaftaran VALUES ('$no_ai','$tgl_daftar','$kode_dokter','$kode_pasien','$petugas_jaga','$bayar','$status_ambil','$catatan')";
$sql = mysql_query($hasil);

foreach($_POST['cek'] as $selected){

    foreach($_POST['cek'] as $selek){
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT kode_cek FROM master_cek where kode_item='$selected'");
    while($koko=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

    print_r($koko);


    $result = "INSERT INTO detail_daftar  VALUES ('',$no_ai','$res','0','','','$selected')";
    $sql = mysql_query($result);    
    print_r($result);

        }
    }
}
```

The Result is..

```
Resource id #5 INSERT INTO detail_daftar VALUES ('',20150206015','Resource id #5','0','','','1011')Resource id #5INSERT INTO detail_daftar VALUES ('',20150206015','Resource id #5','0','','','1011')Resource id #5INSERT INTO detail_daftar VALUES ('',20150206015','Resource id #5','0','','','1011')
```

I am very confused with the resource id. Please help me thank you :)

Comment: What do you want to print?

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing `print_r($res);`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Resource id #4" when I apply print\_r() to an array in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777801/why-do-i-get-resource-id-4-when-i-apply-print-r-to-an-array-in-php)

Comment: Can you please add the html code from which $_POST is coming from?

Comment: the html $_POST is coming from

Comment: is coming from  <label> <?php echo $data['nama_item'] ?> &nbsp; </label><input type="checkbox" name="cek[]" value="<?php echo $data['kode_item'] ?>" >

Answer (score 0):

It because when query is executed using PHP MySql driver it gives you resource id from where you need to fetch actual result.

If you need to get last insert id then you will have to make one more function call

```
print_r(mysql_insert_id());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['cek'] as $selected){

foreach($_POST['cek'] as $selek){
$res = mysql_query("SELECT kode_cek FROM master_cek where kode_item='$selected'");
while($koko=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

print_r($koko);


$result = "INSERT INTO detail_daftar  VALUES ('',$no_ai','$koko['kode_cek']','0','','','$selected')";
$sql = mysql_query($result);    
print_r($result);

    }
}
}
```

You are trying to insert `$res` change that to `$koko['kode_cek']`

Answer (score 0):

Insert query doesn't return array. To get inserted id of executed query you have to call last inserted id function which will return you Id of last inserted record in DB. 
Below function will help to get ID of inserted record.

```
`mysql_insert_id();`
```